# Laravel JOIN DB Raw return hasMany Relathsionship

Tags: laravel, join

i have case in my query, i want expect like this

1. one project **hasMany** User
2. **total_feedback** is calculated from **id** in **feedback** table
   where the **project_id** in the feedback table has a relation to the pivot table, namely **project_user** , i want to calculated how much feedback on a project,

i want **expect** return JSON like this

```
"success": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Project_name": "Project Tania Yessi Laksmiwati",
        "user_name": {
                  "User A",
                   "User B",
                   "User C",
                   "User D",
           }
        "total_feedback": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Project_name": "Project Bakijan Bancar Anggriawan",
         "user_name": {
                  "User F",
                   "User G",
                   "User C",
           }
        "total_feedback": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "Project_name": "Project Mahesa Vega Mahendra",
        "user_name": {
                     "Users A"
                    },
        "total_feedback": 6
    },
```

return JSON above is one project hasMany users

but, now i get return json like this bellow :

```
    "success": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "Project_name": "Project Tania Yessi Laksmiwati",
        "user_name": "Ilyas Simanjuntak",
        "total_feedback": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Project_name": "Project Bakijan Bancar Anggriawan",
        "user_name": "Ilyas Simanjuntak",
        "total_feedback": 0
    },
```

one project return just one users, even though the project with id 1 has 3 users, like **project_user** table like this bellow

```
project_id  |  user_id
1               2
1               4
1               5
```

this is my query

```
    $user = $this->request->attributes->get('_user');

    $query = "SELECT A.id, A.`name` AS Project_name, D.`name` AS user_name, COUNT(C.`id`) AS total_feedback FROM `project` A
                     JOIN `project_user` B ON A.`id` = B.`project_id` AND B.`user_id` = $user->id
                    LEFT JOIN `feedback` C ON C.`project_id` = B.`project_id` AND C.`request_id` = B.`user_id`
                       JOIN `users` D ON D.`id` = B.`user_id`
                    GROUP BY A.`id`";

    $getFeedback = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

but i get project with **ID** 1 just return **one** users,, in my case above how to return one project with many users from database, i use the DB query ,, or any suggestion ? Thanks! regards.

Comment: Please improve your typo in the question. What's more, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have relationships setup, why aren't you using Eloquent for this? You can easily do this with Eloquent `with()` and `withCount()` methods. Assuming you have setup your model relationships correctly, you can do something like this instead:

```php
Auth::user()
    ->projects()
    ->with(['users', function($query) {
        return $query->pluck('name');
    }])
    ->withCount('feedback as total_feedback')
    ->get();
```

Comment: ->withCount('feedback') is return get_feedback_count , how to i change name be total_feedback ?

Comment: Try `withCount('feedback as total_feedback')`

Comment: I only want to display projects that are only owned by the user himself (the user who is currently logged in),, i have table pivot project_user like above., how to get this ??

Comment: thanks ! worked. i use the query but i confused how to count total_feedback, and I just found out that laravel has a function withCount is helpfull